# Absolute div height being cut off inside relative div

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting one of my absolutely positioned divs to display correctly. It's getting cut off unless I set a height for the parent (relative) div which I can't do as I will never know the height required.

I originally wasn't using any absolute positioning but the contents of the `comm` div were wrapping underneath the `avatar` div so I thought absolute positioning would fix it and it has, apart from the text being cut off at the bottom.

This is the structure and you can see what's happening in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfm175ps/).

```css
body {
  background: #212121;
  font-family: arial;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

a.avatar {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

a.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
}

.top {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
}

a.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.posted {
  color: #BBB;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  float: left;
}

p.comm {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrap">
    <a href="https://example.com" class="avatar"><img src="http://www.tangoflooring.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/user-avatar-placeholder.png" /></a>
    <div class="top">
      <a href="https://example.com" class="name">John Doe</a>
      <div class="posted">8 mins ago</div>
    </div>
    <p class="comm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <a href="https://example.com" class="avatar"><img src="http://www.tangoflooring.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/user-avatar-placeholder.png" /></a>
    <div class="top">
      <a href="https://example.com" class="name">Jane Doe</a>
      <div class="posted">11 mins ago</div>
    </div>
    <p class="comm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <a href="https://example.com" class="avatar"><img src="http://www.tangoflooring.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/user-avatar-placeholder.png" /></a>
    <div class="top">
      <a href="https://example.com" class="name">Jimmy Doe</a>
      <div class="posted">18 mins ago</div>
    </div>
    <p class="comm">Ut enim ad minim veniam.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using flexbox to position the element underneath the other? By doing so it will automatically take the full remaining space, without the need of specifying it.

Comment: Just tried flexbox and it wraps the text underneath the avatar which is the same issue I was having when using floats previously. - https://jsfiddle.net/Lw77x3pk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify on your `p.comm` selector like below:

```
p.comm {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this modified css code.

```
body {
  background: #212121;
  font-family: arial;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

a.avatar {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

a.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

a.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.posted {
  color: #BBB;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

p.comm {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `.top` and `.comm` in a `div` and with the use of `flex` you can achieve it

```css
body {
  background: #212121;
  font-family: arial;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  margin:20px auto;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

a.avatar {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
a.avatar img {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.posted {
  color: #BBB;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  float: left;
}

p.comm {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.right {
  max-width: 88%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

    <div class="wrap">
    <a href="https://example.com" class="avatar"><img src="http://www.tangoflooring.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/user-avatar-placeholder.png"></a>
    <div class="right">
     <div class="top">
          <a href="https://example.com" class="name">Jane Doe</a>
          <div class="posted">11 mins ago</div>
        </div>
    <p class="comm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do </p>
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="wrap">
    <a href="https://example.com" class="avatar"><img src="http://www.tangoflooring.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/user-avatar-placeholder.png"></a>
    <div class="right">
     <div class="top">
          <a href="https://example.com" class="name">Jane Doe</a>
          <div class="posted">11 mins ago</div>
        </div>
    <p class="comm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    <div class="wrap">
    <a href="https://example.com" class="avatar"><img src="http://www.tangoflooring.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/user-avatar-placeholder.png"></a>
    <div class="right">
     <div class="top">
          <a href="https://example.com" class="name">Jane Doe</a>
          <div class="posted">11 mins ago</div>
        </div>
    <p class="comm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bfm175ps/6/)